# Jquery file upload submits form on upload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery-fileupload-rails gems to enable users to upload files as part of a form that has other inputs as well.

```
$(function () {
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    progressall: function (e, data) {
     $("#submit").off('click').on('click', function () {  
        data.submit();
     });
     var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
     $('#progress .bar').css(
        'width', progress + '%');
     }
   });
});
```

the uploader works but the problem is that it submits the form as soon as file is uploaded. What I need is to upload the file but only submit when clicking the submit button.

I know there are a lot of similar questions but none seemed to offer a working solution for me. I really appreciate if anyone can help, it's been couple of hours now with no luck

Comment: Move your submit function out of the immediately executed function.

Comment: Thanks Mark, can you explain a bit more please. where can I put the submit function. I tried removing the submit function altogether and the form still gets submitted when a file is uploaded

Comment: Did you try to remove the wrapper function `$(function() { });`